# component-scan classpath subdirectory (a'la plugins + annotation capable)

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, plugins, configuration

Goal:

- List item
- I have a spring webapp project, which is using component scan for configuration and autowiring interface implementation through maven submodules
- the main project is dependant on the other modules thus the jar's of the submodules are placed in the /WEB-INF/lib folder
- the submodules (aka plugins) have common package parent name x.y.z.extension eg. x.y.z.extension.pluginA
- the classes in this package are annotated with @Component or @Configuration
- in the servlet xml configuration i have placed such component-scan information:

Code:

```
<context:spring-configured />
<context:component-scan base-package="x.y.z.extension" />
```

With the mentioned configuration everything is working correctly.

What I would like to achieve:

- List item
- remove dependency of the main webapp maven module and other modules - the core webapp will be shipped without plugins
- create subfolder e.g. "WEB-INF/classes/plugins" in the classpath classes dir
- put there the mentioned jar's from submodules (or extract the jar content to eg. WEB-INF/classes/plugins/pluginA) - this could be done during "plugin installation" with webapp restart after new plugin installation
- spring automagically should detect annotated classes and load it into the application context (and use not annotated classes in the plugin jar (annotated classes are mainly interface implementation but they are using some not annotated classes in the jar))

and ... of course this does not work The classes are not found.

If it possible to achieve this only using spring ecosystem, or should I take a look into other examples e.g. jspf ?
How can I modify classpath scanning with spring and also keep automatic component scanning ?

thanks !

Comment: I think all you need to do is make sure the dir containing the plugin jars is on the classpath.  "WEB-INF/classes" is already on classpath but creating arbitrary dirs below it will most likely trip up the class loader.  As a suggestion why not create a folder external to the web app eg "/home/plugins" and add it to the classpath of the web container.  Or even, if using tomcat, just put your plugins in "<tomcat_home>/lib".

Comment: thanks, i'll try to dig deeper into this